# how to estimate negative values in deep learning context

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have dataset input 2D image and should predict 3D matrix value between [-500 , +500].

My question how to make model predict negative value, which activation function ? specially the range is large also the value must be integer not float.

normlization 0-1 range  make harder to predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is the task here? There are countless ways to do this but which one is optimal depends on a lot more information. You could use a clamped function like tanh or sigmoid and shift/scale as necessary. For example 500tanh or 1000(sigmoid-0.5) both give you outputs in the range -500:500. Alternatively, if you want only discrete values output you can just have 1001 outputs and map each one to a value of -500:500.

Comment: >>" Alternatively, if you want only discrete values output you can just have 1001 outputs and map each one to a value of -500:500."  , YES, I want discrete values , can you please explain about 1001 , what you mean exactly ? how to output 1001 discrets value ?

Comment: to make it clear , the output matrix is representing  indexes in arrays, as reult, the index should accurate and precise as mush as possible

Comment: The output would be a 4d tensor where each 'value' in the 3d tensor is a 1001 element vector where each element maps to a value in -500:500. You take the softmax over this 1001 element vector (for all such vectors in the 3d matrix) and use cross entropy loss for training. For example, the contribution to your total loss of the (0, 0, 0) element of your 3d matrix would be -log(output[0, 0, 0, mapped_target[0, 0, 0]]) where mapped_target[-500]=0, mapped_target[-499]=1, etc. For inference you'd do the argmax over the 1001 element vector to get the value for a single element of the 3d matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a regression task, you do not need any activation function for the last layer. However, scaling/normalization is still recommended, as otherwise would will need way too large weights in the final layer. So I would normalize the data so that your output values are roughly in the range [-3,3]

Comment: hi, I appricatte your comments, if its regression however output should be integer between [-500 , +500] (for example : -22  or +450], is there solution for regression task however output is integer not float ?

Comment: ah sorry I missed the integer part.